# How do you create a UIActionSheet with another View above it?

Tags: objective-c, swift, user-interface

In objective-c, is it possible to create a UIActionSheet with buttons towards the bottom and a View object at the top, with an ImageView and a Label objects inside the View object? If so, any insight to approaching it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

`UIActionSheet` has been deprecated in iOS 8.3. And as your description, `UIActionSheet` also cannot do what you want.

A recommendation is to create a ViewController and add what you want into this. 
Use a modal presentation style of `UIModalPresentationPopover` and `UIPopoverPresentationController` to show this ViewController.

Note, `UIPopoverController` can achieve your requirement, but is has been deprecated in iOS 9.0